# Why does predict() in PCA makes an additional scaling when the data is already scaled?

Tags: r, pca, caret

Imagine I have my PCs after scaling the data with **log10**:

```
preProc<-preProcess(log10(training[,-58]+1), method="pca", pcaComp = 2)
```

Here *preProc$rotation* contains my two PCs.

Now I want to project my new data onto the PCA space by:

```
trainPC<-predict(object = preProc, newdata = log10(training[,-58]+1))
```

Here I scale my new data with **log10**. However it seems like the *predict()* function additionally scales my data with the *scale()* function (can be verified by running: *getS3method("predict", "prcomp")*):

```
scale(newdata, object$center, object$scale) %*% object$rotation
```

Am I understanding this correct, that double-scaling is done in this case (*log10* and then built-in *scale()*)? I actually need only **log10**.

Comment: *To whom it may concern:* Although this looks like a question solely about R code (which would be off topic), this is actually motivated by an incomplete understanding of the issues associated w/ PCA. IMO, it is on topic here.

Comment: Are you saying that the PCA scores returned by `predict` are standardized (mean 0, sd 1)?

Comment: @ttnphns: I think what is happening is that `predict` standardizes the variables before running PCA (i.e. runs PCA on the correlation matrix). I don't think the output scores are standardized though. But I have no experience with these R functions, this is just a guess.

Comment: @ttnphns, I'm pretty sure the OP means that the new dataset `newdata = log10(training[,-58]+1` is standardized to mean 0 & SD 1 before the function multiplies it by the matrix of eigenvectors.

Comment: @gung: It looks like the test data is scaled using the mean and SD of the training data (as it should), so that it's actually not exactly getting "standardized".

Comment: You're right, @amoeba. That was sloppy of me.